# navigate to first and page in material-ui table pagination

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react material-ui tables component and i need to navigate between pages in pagination.
How can i add the option to load the first and the last page, or set a list of all pages in table pagination?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: Material-ui@next has native pagination components, but you will have to implement the page change functionality yourself. https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tables/

Comment: how can i implement a specific fonctionnality for table pagination component?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the first and last page :

```
`<TableCell>
 <IconButton onClick={this.handleFirstPage} >
 <PaginationFirstPage />
 </IconButton>
 <IconButton onClick={this.handleLastPage} >
 <PaginationLastPage />
 </IconButton>
 </TableCell>`
```

but i want to add the first page icon before the previous page icon and the ast page icon after the next icon in tablepagination component of material-ui

```
                                                                                                                  but the position is at the end of pagination and i want to add the first icon  page before the icon of previous page and the last page after the next page
```